# "Sequence contains more than one matching element" with AntiForgeryToken()

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm got this exception in my log table, not in the first time.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains more than one matching element
     at System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
     at System.Web.Helpers.AntiXsrf.ClaimUidExtractor.GetUniqueIdentifierParameters(ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity, String uniqueClaimTypeIdentifier)
     at System.Web.Helpers.AntiXsrf.ClaimUidExtractor.ExtractClaimUid(IIdentity identity)
     at System.Web.Helpers.AntiXsrf.TokenValidator.GenerateFormToken(HttpContextBase httpContext, IIdentity identity, AntiForgeryToken cookieToken)
     at System.Web.Helpers.AntiXsrf.AntiForgeryWorker.GetFormInputElement(HttpContextBase httpContext)
     at System.Web.Helpers.AntiForgery.GetHtml()
     at System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper.AntiForgeryToken()
     at ASP._Page_Views_Account_Signup_cshtml.Execute() in d:\hostingspaces\***\wwwroot\Views\Account\Signup.cshtml:line 23
     at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
     at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
     at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
     at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
     at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
     at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
     at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult)
     at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass1e.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1b(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
     at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState)
     at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
     at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
     at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
     at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__4(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState)
     at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
     at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
     at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

The only clue to solve the problem is the key "Signup.cshtml:line 23", montined in the exception. Also, this is probably related to "AntiForgeryToken" somehow.

This is line 23:

```
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
```

I'm tried to reproduce the problem in my development computer without success.

What is this problem mean?
Can you

Comment: This is very little information to work on. Can you give more relevant contextual code?

Comment: possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20614954/mvc5-antiforgerytoken-claims-sequence-contains-more-than-one-element