# A claim of type 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier' was not present on the provided ClaimsIdentity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, claims-based-identity, asp.net-identity-2

i using claim in login . but it show me this error

> A claim of type `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier` was not present on the provided ClaimsIdentity.

how solve this ?

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        //AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier = ClaimTypes.Email;
        AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier = ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier;
    }
}
```

.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{

    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }

    var identity =new  ClaimsIdentity(new[] { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, model.Email) }, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
        ClaimTypes.Name, ClaimTypes.Role);
    identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, model.Email));
    identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin"));
    identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Sid, "123"));
    AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties
    {
        IsPersistent = model.RememberMe
    }, identity);
    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
}
```

**Update**

[image]

Comment: You have `ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier` in `Application_Start` but use `ClaimTypes.Name` in your `Login`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have `ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier` in `Application_Start` but use `ClaimTypes.Name` in your `Login`

You need to change one or the other so that they match what is expected.

```
protected void Application_Start() {
    //...other code omitted for brevity
    AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier = ClaimTypes.Name;
}
```

You should also make sure that  you are not duplicating claims as this will break the `AntiForgeryToken` call in your view.

As mentioned here [MVC5 AntiForgeryToken Claims/“Sequence contains more than one element”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20614954/mvc5-antiforgerytoken-claims-sequence-contains-more-than-one-element)

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl) {

    if (!ModelState.IsValid) {
        return View(model);
    }

    var identity = new  ClaimsIdentity(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie, ClaimTypes.Name, ClaimTypes.Role);
    identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, model.Email));
    identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin"));
    identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Sid, "123"));
    AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties {
        IsPersistent = model.RememberMe
    }, identity);
    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
}
```

Comment: i do that . but show me this error `Sequence contains more than one matching element`

Comment: Because you are adding `ClaimTypes.Name` more than once. Once in the constructor and again in the following line

Comment: Constructor: `var identity =new  ClaimsIdentity(new[] { **new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, model.Email)** }` and again in next line `identity.AddClaim(**new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, model.Email**))`

Comment: i comment  `identity.AddClaim(**new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, model.Email**))` bu till show me that error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125241/discussion-between-kianoush-and-nkosi).