# IHttpContextAccessor UserId is null

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-3.1

After referring to different questions in StackOverflow, and also following the accepted answer:

[IHttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity shows all null properties in CurrentUserService service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59793111/ihttpcontextaccessor-httpcontext-user-identity-shows-all-null-properties-in-curr)

But still, I couldn't access the `UserId` from the `IHttpContextAccessor`, the value of UserId is null when I am trying to access:

`var UserId = _currentUserService.UserId;`

My `CurrentUserService` Looks:

```
 public class CurrentUserService : ICurrentUserService
    {
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

        public CurrentUserService(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        }

        private bool _init = false;
        private string _userId;
        public string UserId
        {
            get
            {
                if (!_init)
                {
                    _userId = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.User?.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
                    _init = true;
                }
                return _userId;
            }
        }
        ///public string UserId { get { return _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.User?.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier); } }

        public bool IsAuthenticated => _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;

    }
```

When I am not logged in and trying to access the controller, it redirects to the login page. And after the login the value of `_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.User` are also being populated as shown in the image below:

[image]

Is there something I am missing or it is the problem from the framework by design?

An example where I am trying to invoke the `UserId`.

In View:

```
 <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <a asp-action="BorrowRequest" asp-controller="Book" asp-route-bookId="@Model.Id" class="btn btn-primary">
                Request for Borrow
            </a>
        </div>
 </div>
```

In Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
[Authorize]
public async Task<ActionResult> BorrowRequest(int bookId)
{
    try
    {
        var UserId = _currentUserService.UserId;

        await Task.Delay(200);
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
    catch
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: Depends on when you are accessing the context. It must be with the scope of a request.

Comment: Where in your flow is `_currentUserService.UserId;` being invoked?

Comment: @Nkosi I have updated my code. Will that give the answer to your question?

Comment: Check this previous answer I gave for a similar type of question and see if it helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/39934077/5233410

Comment: I also do not see an obvious claim in the picture for the user id. Which claim in the image are you using as the user id?

Comment: Isn't identity add the user id in the claim by itself? do I have to add the user id in the claim?

Comment: How are you registering the `IHttpContextAccessor`. Transient or Singleton?

Comment: @Ergis I am doing `services.AddHttpContextAccessor();`

Comment: Aight. Why don't you use `SignInManager` instead?

Comment: I need to get the user details outside the controller.

Comment: Wdym? You can inject it in a service too.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your way, how would I get the user to pass into the `SignInManager`, if I am not getting the user detail, outside the controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something was replacing the name for claims for the user id from `ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier` to `sub`, which is shown in the figure.

So, To not let Microsoft Identity override claim names I used:

`JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();`  just before the `app.UseAuthentication()` in the API startup.

Referring: [Why is ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier not mapping to 'sub'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57998262/why-is-claimtypes-nameidentifier-not-mapping-to-sub)